# CSS Transition on newly created psuedo element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a fade effect on a pseudo element but am having difficulty as i cannot use javascript on this element.

I have an example of something similar to what i am trying to do here but i cannot get the element to fade in as transitions do not seem to work when the element is created.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrxPXJ

```
.hoverhere.dim::before {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
 }
```

I am adding a class to a div so that the pseudo element is created after matching with the above css however cannot work out how to animate this.

I can probably get it to work without psuedo elements like below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Oxwzvv

However was wondering if there is a way without changing my markup to include an empty div.

Comment: Why can't you use JS on that element?

Comment: $(".hoverhere::before") doesn't work and  i read that i can't as it isnt actually in the DOM or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're saying you want this?

```js
$('.hoverhere')
  .mouseenter(function() { $(this).addClass('dim'); })
  .mouseleave(function() { $(this).removeClass('dim'); });
```

```css
.hoverhere {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.hoverhere::before {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.hoverhere.dim::before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<p>RANDOM TEXT HERE</p>
<div class="hoverhere">HOVER ON ME</div>
<p>MORE RANDOM TEXT HERE</p>
```

What it needed was to have a starting point established for the `opacity`.

---

If this is just for hovering, you don't need the JS at all.

```css
.hoverhere {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.hoverhere::before {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.hoverhere:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<p>RANDOM TEXT HERE</p>
<div class="hoverhere">HOVER ON ME</div>
<p>MORE RANDOM TEXT HERE</p>
```

Comment: Swear i did that at some point and it didnt work! Anyway your my hero.

Comment: @TylerH: I think he's just using that for the demo.

Comment: I can use javascript. Its just i cant target pseudo elements like $(".hoverhere::before") so i couldnt use it to do what i intended. Also with this answer i dont want the element there by default. This i think has the element there constantly. Let me try this and see what happens in my situation however

Comment: @harri: I updated it to set `visibility` to `hidden` when the class isn't there.

Comment: @harri: I added a second demo that doesn't rely on any JavaScript. If all you need this for is the hover effect, then I'd let CSS handle it.

Comment: Yeah im thinking that may be better but yeah all is working perfect in my situation. Will try without JS also as would prefer that.

Comment: Legend. Annoyingly without the JS the opacity doesn't seem to be reverting on my site which i don't quite get.

Comment: Let me know if you can reproduce it in a demo.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Bascially it's like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrxPXJ . I have a megamenu and the menu is like the box. My menu however does show above the transparency layer (unlinke example) but without the js the transparency layer seems to expand the .hoverhere hover area to 100% / 100% so it never unhovers.

Comment: It's annoying because the psuedo elements are created within the element and so i would probably need to change the markup to get it to work without JS in this case.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what to do about that if you need it to be full window size.

Comment: Im not going to worry about it JS way works fine although yeah it would of been nice.